# Securing a simple API with ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I feel somewhat lost in trying to secure a simple ASP.NET 5 (MVC6) Web API scenario because of seemingly outdated options/informations or too complex solutions. Also, the majority of existing SO posts seem to rely on older technologies like Web API 2. Discussions about security in general are often controversial.

So I will try to describe my scenario as precise as possible and hope for some recommendations:

- I have a very old database/dbms that runs on a company server
- the data stored in this database should be made available (read-only) to
  certain client applications that are under control of the company
  itself or partner developers (f.e. smartphone app developer)
- no authorization is needed! Every authenticated user should have access
  to all data
- no user management is needed! A single set of credentials
  would be enough for the very limited number of client applications
- it would be nice for testing and presentation purposes if a browser or
  at least some of the public REST clients could be used for accessing the data
- we would rather avoid having to install another dbms for user management (since there should be only one set of user credentials)
- access via SSL should be the only option
- ASP.NET 5/Core 1.0 is the desired development framework for the API

Does ASP.NET 5 offer something out of the box to secure this API or do I need 3rd-party options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options.

1. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3
2. https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server
3. https://github.com/openiddict

The latter is perhaps the simplest to use.

Comment: This looks like a good starting point. The posts and presentations by Dominick Baier are just awesome so I will try with IdentityServer3 first.